# Handling bit arrays in C without padding

Tags: c, embedded, bit

I'm writing a C program that runs on the Altera NIOS II processor. The program has to interface to a VHDL module on an FPGA test board through a specific memory location. My interface is provided through a Macro, which specifies a base memory address. The VHDL programmer has allocated 32-bits of memory off of that base address, which I'm to fill with binary data separated into four "elements", i.e. [0-11|12-15|16-23|24-31].

My question is, what is the best way to handle these array "elements" as separate data types. I'd like to declare the entire array as a structure to handle the data and declare the different fields using bit-fields, but it's my understanding that this will introduce padding into the 32 bit array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it's my understanding that [using bit fields] will introduce padding into the 32 bit array

Using bit fields will not introduce padding, unless you explicitly request it: language standard prohibits the compier from padding in between bit fields:

> **C99 Standard, section 6.7.2.1.10:** If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined.

You can force padding to happen by specifying a bit field of zero width, like this:

```
struct hw_reg {
    int a:10;
    int :0; // Yes, this is legal.
    int b:6;
};
```

In your case, sufficient space remains after the first 12 bits to allocate the next four, so there will be no padding. If you needed to split the register differently (say, 12-5-7-8), the use of padding would be implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

> binary data separated into four "elements", i.e.
>   [0-11|12-15|16-23|24-31].

I'd try as

```
struct vhdl_data {
    uint32_t a : 12;   // bits  0-11
    uint32_t b :  4;   // bits 12-15
    uint32_t c :  8;   // bits 16-23
    uint32_t d :  8;   // bits 24-31
};
```